# I am getting an 'cannot read property url'

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension

I am working on creating a google extension, and part of it is to get the current URL when you click on a button. The error I get is:

```
Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
at Object.callback (chrome-extension://enpjjbneobjdmeihjdfpmpenhhkhpkif/popup.js:3:23)
at setURL (chrome-extension://enpjjbneobjdmeihjdfpmpenhhkhpkif/popup.js:2:14)"
```

Here is my code

```
function setURL(){
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, 
function(tabs) {
var url = tabs[0].url;
document.getElementById("URL").value =  url;
});

}
function clickHandler() {

setTimeout(setURL, 1000);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.getElementById("getURL").addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: That means that `tabs[0]` is undefined, I guess the array is empty for some reason?

Comment: `url` is present only when you have [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) for that URL. If possible, use [`"activeTab"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission instead. Also, use `currentWindow` instead of `lastFocusedWindow`.

Comment: Changing from 'lastFocusedWindow' to currentWindow got it to work! thanks @wOxxOm